# Modify PHP code SocialEngine

Tags: php, html, css, socialengine

Good evening,
I tried searching for answers but have not found anything on the site:
How can I change the code (PHP, HTML, CSS) in SocialEngine?
That is: I have purchased a license on behalf of a company, but can not find, for example, the home page to change (www.mysite.com/MEMBERS/HOME/)
Thanks so much.

Comment: I would look through their documentation...

Comment: I've already looked, but did not understand English very well I would not know where to look on the site.
Can you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin the joke is that they haven't any technical documentation published.

Comment: @KirkHammett exactly, they don't have anything like documentation, and if you ask via e-mail, they will reply that they can not offer support even though we are a business.

Comment: I googled before I posted that comment... I saw some resources out there.  If you want to change the code, go in from the back end; the website says you have complete access to the source code.

Comment: From what I read [here](https://www.socialengine.com/support/php/faq#faqcat12)... just connect to your server from putty.  Is [this](http://socialenginehelp.com/topic/128-how-to-change-url/) also something you posted?

Answer (score 0):

All pages are handled via "widgets" in the admin panel.
Under admin panel, go to Layout Menu>Layout
Then select the page you wish to edit.

Perhaps you can run this page through google translate to have it converted to your native language?

http://support.socialengine.com/php/customer/portal/articles/1641082-admin-panel---layout->-layout-editor

Comment: Thank you for your reply SEFellah, but I need to know how to change the PHP code directly, because from the Admin Panel changes are very limited :/

Answer (score 0):

Which page you want change and here all page acts as widget. If you want change home page means go to theme module and find view section here home page code is available.

Answer (score 0):

in the file manger follow the route: application->module->activity

here you can see the model,view and controllers for that module. if you want to edit the HTML then go the views->scripts folder and search the **_activityText.tpl** file. if you want to change in the css then you can change it directly from the admin panel ->layout editor->theme.css. if you want to change the php code then you can find it in both views,controlles and model folder. search your file according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom widgets by creating a new one plugin in the admin panel. Then upload your newly created widget. Navigate to:

> ***application >> widgets >> "NameOfWidget"***.

Open `index.tpl` and `controller.php`.

In the index file, you can run traditional HTML code render custom HTML as a widget. If you want to add logic and PHP to that html, add it using controller.php.

If you want to change the whole theme/look, see at Vipin Chahal's reply. 
Cheers!